# Pytorch doesn't work with CUDA in PyCharm/IntelliJ

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, pytorch

I have just downloaded PyTorch with CUDA via Anaconda and when I type into the Anaconda terminal:

```
import torch
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    print('it works')
```

then he outputs that;  that means that it worked and it works with PyTorch.

But when I go to my IDE (PyCharm and IntelliJ) and write the same code, it doesn't output anything.

Could someone please explain to me how I can somehow get this to work in the IDE?

Comment: do you actually have cuda installed?

Comment: Yes version 11.0

Comment: Pytorch works outside of pycharm so it's clearly not an issue with cuda or hardware. Did you configure your pycharm project to use your existing conda environment?

Comment: Do you use the same conda environment in both cases?
Have you tried running your file in PyCharm's built-in terminal?

Comment: It doesn't work in the terminal of PyCharm either

Comment: @jodag how do I do that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was driving me mad as well... What finally helped me was the first link that says to use PyCharm "Terminal" to run the pip install command (from the PyTorch website). That fixed all my problems. (I had installed pytorch 3 times by that time and tried different interpreters...)

https://www.datasciencelearner.com/how-to-install-pytorch-in-pycharm/

pip install torch==1.8.0+cu111 torchvision==0.9.0+cu111 torchaudio===0.8.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

I hope this helps save someone hours of headache.   :)

Answer (score 2):

I also spent over 10 hours trying to figure out what was wrong. I ended up checking if there is something wrong with interpreter.
What was the problem is version of python (I had v. 3.8). After upgrading to newest version, problem was solved.

Check your version using command:

```
python --version
```

If your version is old (current is 3.9.2), install newest one from official python site:
https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-392/

After installation make sure you using newer version (use command above)

Answer (score 2):

Another possible root of the problem is running a Flatpak version of Pycharm. Took me some time to figure out, but Flatpak does not load user specific environment variables files (i.e. `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile` and conda environment). I have deleted Flatpak version and installed a snap version (`sudo snap install [pycharm-professional|pycharm-community] --classic`) and it loads the proper PATH which allows loading CUDA correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.

Inspired by @the-lay answer, calling `import os; os.system('')` resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I made it work on my Windows Machine with CUDA using PyCharm.

I uninstalled the existing torch package by selecting `torch` and clicking the `-` sign. Please see screenshot below

[image: Uninstall PyTorch with CPU capability only]

After it has successfully uninstalled. I clicked on the plus sign again and searched for torch in the search bar. Then in the bottom right corner, I checked the options checkbox and entered the following command

```
pip install -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Click on the `Install Package` button to install PyTorch with CUDA capability. Please see the screenshot below. I hope this helps.

[image: Pip Install for PyTorch with CUDA]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was the specific build of PyTorch I had installed. To check the PyTorch build:

```py
import torch
print(torch.__version__)
```

For me, it showed `2.0.1+cpu`, indicating a CPU-only version. I reinstalled PyTorch using the [official website's](https://pytorch.org/) recommended method. Now it shows `2.0.1+cu118`, indicating a CUDA-compatible build.

---